# SQLite: Select all date-value-pairs where the distance between each date and the first date is a multiple of a specific period

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, date

I am working with SQLite and Python and try to get these specific dates (and corresponding values). I think an example explainst best what I am looking for.
Consider selecting from this data:

```
-(2011-01-02, 4.0)
-(2011-01-14, 5.0)
-(2011-02-02, 5.5)
-(2011-02-07, 6.5)
-(2011-02-12, 7.0)
-(2011-02-15, 4.0)
-(2011-03-02, 2.5)
-(2011-03-09, 3.5)
```

with a period-distance of **one month** (or a multiple) between the first date and all the dates we are looking for we return this data:

```
-(2011-01-02, 4.0)
-(2011-02-02, 5.5)
-(2011-03-02, 2.5)
```

I was looking for an SQL-statement which provides me with this data, if that is possible.

**Additional question:**
if there is no date-point which is exactly a multiple of a month away from the initial date, how can I get the nearest date in my database?

I hope that my explanation is clear enough. If not, thanks for telling.

Comment: My gut tells me this just isn't possible with SQLite SQL. It might be possible using Postgres WITH RECURSIVE, but it would probably have the same complexity as doing it in a stored procedure. Since SQLite data is local, I'd probably just loop over the possible dates and do a separate query for each.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try to figure out this problem all day. I was hoping that there is some kind of loop command in SQLite, but as far as I read, there isn't.
An alternative I had in mind was pulling all the dates from the database 
`curs.execute('''SELECT date, value FROM stockPrices WHERE name= ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date ASC;''', (name, start, end))`
and then writing a function in Python which selects the specific dates. But I am still hoping for a more elegant way.

Comment: You could pull the minimum date and the maximum date from the table, then in Python, loop over all the "candidate dates" in this range. For each of these, `select * from stockPrices where date between [candidate - period] and [candidate + period] order by abs(julianday(date)-julianday(?)) asc limit 1`. Depending on whether SQLite and the Python drivers allow this, you might also use a subquery and do something like `select ([subquery]) from values ([candidate1]),([candidate2])`, but that's probably a little out of scope for SQLite.

Comment: Alternately you can fake a "constant table" in SQLite with `select [candidate1] as candidate union select [candidate2] as candidate union …` but that's hideous and probably pointless if you're not accessing the database over the network.

Comment: I think I will use python for the specific dates now. I will pull out all dates I have from the database and then iterater over them in python. Everytime a date is in a new month I will write it into a new list. That is not as flexible as defining any period between dates and also not very elegant, but sufficient for my purpose. I will post my code, when it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this won't be a flexible enough solution for your needs, but to answer your question directly, here is a query that gets you what you need.

Also, since you didn't specify table/column names, my test table I used is called `foo`, and has columns `created` and `value`.

```
select
    foo.created, foo.value
from 
    -- Subquery to pick first record to base rest of query on
    (
        select
            created,
            strftime('%d', created) as day
        from
            foo
        order by
            created
        limit 1
    ) as bar

    -- Join all rows in foo that are greater than that found in 'bar'
    -- and has the same day of the month.
    join foo
        on foo.created >= bar.created
           and strftime('%d', foo.created) = bar.day
```

Results:

```
2011-01-02|4.0
2011-02-02|5.5
2011-03-02|2.5
```

---

**NOTE** - this is probably fairly inefficient, due to all the `strftime`s being done (I'm assuming no index can be used here).

**NOTE 2** - This query doesn't deal with intervals other than *exactly* one month, do anything special if two records have the same date, or recognize when there are gaps in the the data (example: if the `2011-02-02` date was missing, it would still return the `2011-03-02` date).

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for your answer. In the meantime I "solved" my problem circumventing SQL and working out a solution in Python. Unfortunately, with timedelta I could only add day-intervals not month, so I used 30 days instead of one month. Not perfect, but the best solution I found. I actually wrote all dates between the start- and end-date into a dictionary, filled out the missing dates (weekends etc.) with the values from the previous day, then looped through the dict and picked every 30th value. Not the solution I was looking for, but OK anyway. Still, thanks for your support!

Comment: No problem.. As I stated in the answer, I figured it might not be as flexible as you were looking for, but I figured I'd post anyway.  More of a challenge than anything else.  :)